# RHEL/CentOS Bootable USB Drive with Extra Files

Tags: rhel, bootable

I have a 128GB USB Drive and I can bootstrap and install REHL 8.3.  I would like to place additional files on the USB Drive that are readable after the system is installed.  Internet research yields how to do this in a Windows environment -- nothing about Red Hat or CentOS.

I can mount the USB Drive after the installation.  When I do this, I receive a message that the USB Drive is write-protected and the mount is performed read-only.  This is likely due to filesystem type ISO 9660.  Write-protection is a good thing as I do not want to change any content on the partition I use to install the server. It is likely not a good idea to add extra files to the ISO prior to creating the USB for the same reason.

I would like to boot/install from one partition and have a second partition that is available for read/write after the system is installed -- using the same USB Drive.  It would be ideal to install the USB Drive and never remove it for the life of the system.  This provides an "if all else fails" starting point on the remote server.

Comment: Your choices are to create a custom iso that has not only the installer but the files and other configurations that you wish or to use the left over space (or create a 2 partition drive) of the flash drive to store the files. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: I would prefer to create a multiple partition USB Drive.  One partition has the installer files and is used to boot/install and is read-only.  A second partition would be USB storage that is mounted in /etc/fstab and available for read/write when the machine is running.  This second partition will initially contain files needed to gain access to AWS S3 to download, install and start applications.

Comment: So I have been working on this for a little bit and I think it would be easier to go with the first option of creating a custom ISO installer that happens to have the files and configurations that you want. Or a cloned image that can be restored from. Ultimately, having one 16 GB flash drive with the installer and another with your configuration files etc would work. Can you help provide more context as to why you specifically need this one 1 single flash drive and not, a restorable backup image of some kind?

Comment: I am building a server that will be installed in a remote location -- two hours away by car.  I would like to have the partitioned USB installed in the server permanently as an option of last resort.  If I can create a system that has No manual intervention it would be great.  Install from the USB, reboot the server, download from AWS and start applications -- without manual intervention.  This is my goal.

Comment: Red Hat does not provide the ability to create a Live USB installer but you can create a custom live USB using a tool and it will have anything you have installed and configured, such as access to AWS. From here you could do a debootstrap style reinstall or recovery. Alternatively, you could use an out of band management tool to do a reinstall and then after that scp in your configuration files. Would you like to be pointed in the direction of a custom live USB?

Comment: I found the following which might be simular. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959  This will create a custom ISO that includes a kickstart and any other files I need.  I thought the dual partition UBS was going to be the solution -- but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: That's as good as I could find too. It makes sense to me that most linux distros are Debian based. Red Hat just does not support the custom live boots as well. Best of luck! If you want I can draft up an answer or you can and I will certainly give it a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two strategies to resolve this issue:

- create a USB Drive with multiple partitions: the installer which is read-only and another partition with additional files -- perhaps read-write.
- create a custom ISO which contains all the needed files and place it on the USB Drive read-only.

It seems the second approach is best for my scenario.  I found a documented solution here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/60959 . This will create a custom ISO that includes a kickstart configuration and any other needed files.

My thanks to kemotep for to helping resolve this.